# How to handle events on child element in angular2 Component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Suppose I have a component which has several very small child elements in it.
If it were a small number of child elements I could have separated them out into their own components, but due to large number of small child elements I doubt this is the right way to do it, as I would end up creating several separate components.

So I am not sure how I go about them.

Thanks

**Edit**

```
<div> <!-- main component -->
<div>Content</div>
<span>Delete</span>
<span>Like</span>
<span>dislike</span>
<span>report</span>
<span>Edit</span>
<span>Share</span>
</div>
```

I have something like the code above and the text can very well represent what actions can be performed on any mouse event.

Comment: What kind of events? What should happen when an event is fired. Please be a bit more specific and add some code that demonstrates what you're doing.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Just added some template of what I am trying to do.

Comment: What about the rest of my questions. What event? What should happen? What's the problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I think the text in the elements are clear enough to tell what action is to be performed with any mouse event. To be more specific (click, mouseover, mousedown etc.) and each element on any event needs to call some method, which would probably do some validation and may decide to call some api.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but I think there is almost no information at all to work with. No information what the problem is or what the expected behavior is, ...

Answer (score 1):

```ts
<div (click)="doSomething($event)" 
     (mouseover)="doSomething($event)" 
     (mousedown)="doSomething($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add native elements events to event handlers without introducing too much javascript code in the template. If you inject using `@ViewChildren` instead `@ViewChild` an array is provided.

[Angular2 native events handling and rxjs](https://embed.plnkr.co/jPADImb1NSwzrwfow5A8/)